# CDI conditional Bean with Instance<T>

Tags: java, cdi

I have the necessity to provide the correct Bean implementation at runtime.

The common interface:

```
public interface MyInterface { ... }
```

The implementations:

```
@Named("one")
class MyInterfaceImpl1 implements MyInterface { ... }

@Named("two")
class MyInterfaceImpl2 implements MyInterface { ... }

@Named("three")
class MyInterfaceImpl3 implements MyInterface { ... }
```

Notice these classes are package-private.

I then wrote a `@Produces` method:

```
@Produces
@Singleton
MyInterface getMyInterface(
        final Instance<MyInterface> myInterfaceImplementations,
        final Configuration configuration) {
    // Might be one, two or three.
    final String parameter = configuration.getString("value");
    return myInterfaceImplementations.select(new NamedLiteral(parameter)).get();
}
```

Is this the correct way to go, or is there a better solution?

Comment: Your solution seems fine, except for 2 details: (1) Are you sure the `@Singleton` does what you intend it to do? I would use `@ApplicationScoped`. (2) If the produced bean is indeed intended to be a singleton, you are creating N-1 beans for no reason (unless used elsewhere by name). This may be serious or not, depending on how "heavy" the unused beans are.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos Hi! Yeah I don't really need the object to be proxied, I only need the container to instantiate it once per JVM.
For the (2) point, I don't think I'm getting it, could you please elaborate more? Thanks! Mmh are you saying the Producer method will be called for each injection point, even if it is marked as Singleton?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution would work fine, here are my 0.02$ just to make sure you intended it that way:

What Nikos Paraskevopoulos meant in his comment is that your are effectively creating four beans to inject one. `MyInterfaceImpl1`, `MyInterfaceImpl2`, `MyInterfaceImpl3` are all legitimate beans for injection anywhere in the app. If these beans are heavy, creation may take some time, also the ability to inject them anywhere might not be intended? And then there is your producer method - the fourth bean - which I assume is ultimately the only one you are after.

Secondly, the three implementation beans have different scope from the producer method. If they are eligible for injection, in your case it seems logical that they share same scope perhaps?

Thirdly, using `@Singleton`. I would also advice for `@ApplicationScoped`, there is no harm and no overhead by having a proxy. You won't be able to tell the difference and can easily avoid some unpleasant surprises with CDI singleton (which doesn't behave like EJB singleton).

Comment: Yes, spot on. I don't want to have unnecessary beans. I need only a single implementation, as singleton, to be around the container. Could you elaborate on how to avoid this situation? Thanks! Keep in mind I need to maintain those classes as package private, and they're not accessible to the producer method.

Comment: If you need singleton-like behaviour, that's `@ApplicationScoped`. So you cannot change the actual impl classes? In that case (as long as it's package private and producer is elsewhere), your solution seems like the only clean solution. Perhaps you could play around with the producer being an enabled alternative to make sure any injection of `MyInterface` is routed via the producer method?

Comment: The routing alternative sounds good. Are you thinking about the Alternative annotation? Something like annotating each Impl with Alternative?

Comment: I was thinking the other way around - make the producer method `@Alternative` and add `@Priority(x)` to enable it. That way any `@Inject MyInterface` will use the producer.

Comment: I'm on CDI 1.1 and Priority is applicable only over types. But thanks for the idea, if i'll ever make them upgrade to Java EE 8

Comment: Ups sorry, forgot Priority doesn't go to method. You enable/select it via `beans.xml` by listing the class declaring it. See [this part of CDI spec](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#declaring_selected_alternatives_bean_archive). Note that `beans.xml` enable it on a per archive basis, so with multiple bean archives in place, you may need to have this in multiple `beans.xml` files.

Comment: Basically I need to use <class>my.package.ProducerClass</class>, right?

Comment: Yes, just make sure it is in the right bean archive.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: @Siliarus 
You cannot annotate the producer method with `@Alternative` and `@Priority` together. Since `@Priority` has TYPE,PARAMETER as Target.

Comment: @v_schoener True, back then (2 years now?) I probably failed to realize they never made it possible to add it to methods as well - there was even an issue for it.

Comment: @Siliarus every time I wonder about such things like above which should be provided out-of-the-box from the framework / specification. Here CDI/Jakarta EE. Instead I have to implement it on my own. On the other hand there is Spring/Spring Boot which offers a lot other things which cannot be provided by Jakarta EE.

Answer (score 0):

I think a more elegant solution would be to let the CDI do all the magic ;-)
Something like:

```
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.CDI;

@Produces
@Singleton
MyInterface getMyInterface(final Configuration configuration) {
    // Might be one, two or three.
    final String parameter = configuration.getString("value");
    Set<MyInterface> candidates = CDI.current().getBeanManager().getBeans(parameter);
    return ( candidates.size()>0 ? candidates.get(0) : null);
}
```

You could also use the alternate signature of getBeans() signature to play with qualifiers when looking for a particular impl of your interface:
cfr https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/inject/spi/BeanManager.html#getBeans-java.lang.reflect.Type-java.lang.annotation.Annotation...-

Comment: So basically I should leave the implementation classes as they are and get the correct one via BeanManager. What's the difference? I mean, the Instance<T> object is created by CDI itself

Comment: You do not need anymore your factory class (myInterfaceImplementations).

Comment: But it wasn't "my" factory, it was the CDI injectable Instance class: https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/1.1/javax/enterprise/inject/Instance.html That's why I asked